# Trouble creating basic loop within one .csv

Tags: r, loops

again I apologize if this is a trivial question. I'm still new to R but I am determined to learn. I have one original .csv file (lets call it Original.Data) that I am working with. I am basically reorganizing that spreadsheet. I am taking each row and transforming it into a column and then stacking each row as columns underneath each other using bind_rows.

I have created the code necessary to organize the first row how I wanted. Now I'm trying to create a loop to do this for all rows in the Original. Here is the code I created:

Rows 1:3 basically headers and are eventually deleted but not yet becuase they serve an initial purpose. Only row 5 is necessary for the final spreadsheet.

```
    New.Data <-data.frame(t(Original.Data[c(1:3,5),]))

    colnames(New.Data) <-c("patid","Day","Week","SD")
    New.Data[,1] <- New.Data[1,4]

    New.Data$Day <- as.numeric(as.character(New.Data$Day))
    New.Data$SD <- as.numeric(as.character(New.Data$SD))
    New.Data$Week <- as.numeric(as.character(New.Data$Week))

    New.Data <- New.Data[ which(New.Data$Day<=New.Data[3,4]),]
```

This last line is creating a base spreadsheet where I am transferring all of the data to."Base" was already created before hand.

```
    Final.Base <-bind_rows(Base,New.Data)
```

My idea is basically to do something like naming New.Data as New.Data1 for example and having the loop create multiple New.Data for each row and basically binding them all into the Final.Base. So Row 1 (or row 5 actually) is created in to New.Data 1 and row 2 into New.Data 2, etc.

Also, in my first line of code:

```
    New.Data <-data.frame(t(Original.Data[c(1:3,5),]))
```

The only thing I believe that would need to change is the last number "5". It would need to increase by one in every iteration of the loop.

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you want to do. A little bit of data would be good. But here is something that sounds like what you are asking. It takes a column and tacks it on to the next column and so forth to give you a vector of the stacked values"

```
mtcars

out <- c()
for(i in 1:ncol(mtcars)){
  intermediate <- mtcars[,i]

  out <- c(out, intermediate)
}
```